# How to cast an HTMLElement to a React element?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React application that uses an external library in Vanilla JS that creates DOM elements using `document.createElement(...)`. Some of this data I want to insert into my React elements. If I have a simple application:

```
let sub = React.createElement('p', null, 'Made with React'),
    main = React.createElement('div', null, [sub])

React.render(main, document.getElementById('app'));
```

It renders with the content `<p data-reactid=".0.0">Made with React</p>`. If I try it with `document.createElement` instead, nothing is rendered.

```
let sub = document.createElement('p');
sub.innerText = 'Not React';
let main = React.createElement('div', null, [sub])

React.render(main, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I have currently found a workaround using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
let sub = document.createElement('p');
sub.innerText = 'Not React';
let main = React.createElement('div', {dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {__html: sub.outerHTML}});

React.render(main, document.getElementById('app'));
```

This renders but doesn't seem safe. What is the proper way to append HTMLElement as React child elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an elegantly simple solution I discovered to include vanilla HTML Elements to a React project using [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div ref={ ref => ref.appendChild(this.props.child) }></div>;
  }
}
```

Assume you have a vanilla paragraph element you want to display:

```
const para = document.createElement('p');
para.innerText = 'Hello world!';
```

Just create a container for it like this to render alongside your other React elements:

```
<Container child={ para }/>
```

Comment: This helped me.  For anyone who needs to use this with `useCallback`, the signature of the `ref` attribute of a `div` element is `(element: HTMLDivElement | null): void`.  If the element is something other than a `div`, the type will be the corresponding `HTMLElement` type.

Answer (score 1):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` can be used safely with HTML sanitizers. Lots of libraries are available to prevent `XSS`.

`React.createElement()` returns virtual dom javascript object, `document.createElement()` returns dom object.
We are using javascript objects to manage to diff efficiently and update costly `dom`, we would not want to fallback to dom elements unless explicitly needed,

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I was using the Vanilla JS `document.createElement()` copied over from a different application.

**The fix was to use `React.createElement()` instead**. So I went from this:

```
const courseFrame = document.createElement('div');
courseFrame.className = 'frame';
courseFrame.id = frameId;
```

to this:

```
const courseFrame = React.createElement(
    'div',
    { className:'frame', id: frameId, style: { backgroundColor: colorCode}},
    elements
);
```

where `elements` was an array of other elements that I wanted to insert into this div, as shown by this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58200373/how-to-append-child-to-react-element). This is because functions like `appendChild()` don't exist for React elements, and so you need to work around that.